# Why is bundler not able to install rake even though rake appears to be present?

Tags: rake, bundler, rbenv

I'm having some trouble with rbenv and bundler.  When I bundle install on my app, I get an error saying that an error occurred while installing Rake.

I'm thinking this has something to do with rbenv not pointing to the write path for gems -- but I'm not positive.

Why is bundler not able to install rake when rake appears to be present?

**Console Output**

```
deploy@telemed-test:/u/apps/telemed_solutions/current$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..

NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occured while installing rake (0.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
deploy@telemed-test:/u/apps/telemed_solutions/current$ 

deploy@telemed-test:/u/apps/telemed_solutions/current$ rbenv version
1.9.3-p125 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)

deploy@telemed-test:/u/apps/telemed_solutions/current$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.1.3)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.6.6, 1.5.4)
minitest (2.12.1, 2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be time to upgrade rubygems. Some of the specification files may be calling rubygems methods that don't exist in your version.

Run `gem --version` to check your current version.

And `gem update --system` to upgrade to the latest.